# Populate other HTML table cells with a dropdown from another Table Cell

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I am having to create a contacts list for my team to implement on our website and since there are a large number of contacts, I would like to have only a single table cell with a drop down menu and once clicked, it will populate the other cells next to it with the respected information based on the selection.

I am very new to HTML so I am not even sure how to make the dropdown work.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="text-align:center;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Division</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>CTI</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="overflow-y:scroll; height:200px;">
      <tr>
        <td class="select">
          <select>
            <option value="department">Department</option>
            <option value="saab">Division</option>
            <option value="number">Number</option>
            <option value="cti">CTI</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td class="select">
          <select>
            <option value="billing">billing</option>
            <option value="retention">retention</option>
            <option value="sales">sales</option>
            <option value="support">support</option>
            <option value="management">management</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          Number
        </td>
        <td>
          CTI
        </td>
        <td>
          Email
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

So far the answer I got below doesn't quite do what I am looking for.

Below I have added a picture of what my table looks like with CSS and I would like to have the first two cells populate the Department and its division. The other cells will populate themselves based on the selections of the first two:

[image: Contacts Table Idea]

Answer (score 0):

Trying this

```
   <tr>
        <td>
        <select>        
                <option value="department-1">Department</option>
                <option value="department-2">Department</option>
                <option value="department-3">Department</option>
                <option value="department-4">Department</option>
                <option value="department-5">Department</option>
        </select>
        </td>   

        <td>
        <select>        
                <option value="division-1">Division</option>
                <option value="division-2">Division</option>
                <option value="division-3">Division</option>
                <option value="division-4">Division</option>
                <option value="division-5">Division</option>
        </select>
        </td> 
    </tr>
```

And just keep adding

Comment: I updated my code above, but its not quite doing what I want with your response. I want to have dropdown 1 select the department, drop down 2 will populate the areas available to those departments and once both are selected it will populate the other table cells with the relevant information.

Comment: I've updated the code. Is this more along what you want? You can just edit what you want the department name to be

Comment: Ive got the part about adding the drop downs, but what I would like to see is the first one showing all the departments. Once you select which one you want, the second drop down will allow you to select the area. Once you have all of them selected, the other table cells will populate with the information based on the two dropdowns.